How to get distinct array values from nested array
I would like to get distinct studentId and classNo from a nested array objects.
Const arr = [
{
    "studentId": 70,
    "data": [      
      {
        "studentId": 70,
        "teacher": "Syam",
        "classNo": 100,
      },      
      {
        "studentId": 70,
        "teacher": "Mathew",
        "classNo": 101,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "studentId": 69,
    "data": [
      {
        "studentId": 69,
        "teacher": "Sam",
        "classNo": 102,
      },
      {
        "studentId": 69,
        "teacher": "Chris",
        "classNo": 101,
      },  
    ]
  }
]

I would like to populate result of unique classNo array based on studentId...
expecting like this..
[
  {studentId: 70, classNo: [100, 101]},
  {studentId: 60, classNo: [102, 101]}
]

I have tried below code and not getting the required result.
arr.map((dt) => dt.data.map((item)=> item.studentId).filter((item, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === i))

Please anyone help me to resolve this scenario.

What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Loop array, add values to ID map, filter each array to have only unique values

Does this answer your question? Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)

I have tried.
arr.map((dt) => dt.data.map((item)=> item.studentId).filter((item, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === i && item !== ""))
i am getting result like this.
[[100,101],[102, 101]]

A combination of .map(), flat() and .reduce will do the trick:


const arr = [
{
"studentId": 70,
"data": [      
  {
    "studentId": 70,
    "teacher": "Syam",
    "classNo": 100,
  },      
  {
    "studentId": 70,
    "teacher": "Mathew",
    "classNo": 101,
  },
]
  },
  {
"studentId": 69,
"data": [
  {
    "studentId": 69,
    "teacher": "Sam",
    "classNo": 102,
  },
  {
    "studentId": 69,
    "teacher": "Chris",
    "classNo": 101,
  },  
]
  }
];

const res=Object.entries(
 arr
  .map(({data})=>data)
  .flat()
  .reduce((a,{studentId:id,classNo:n})=>
    ((a[id]??=[]).push(n),a),{})
 ).reduce((a,[k,v])=>(a.push({studentId:k,classNo:v}),a),[])
console.log(res);



